Control label location in Manipulate
Consider this simple code:
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 8}, 
  PlotStyle -> {u, v}], {{u, Automatic, "Sin"}, {None, 
   Automatic}}, {{v, Automatic, "Cos"}, {None, Automatic}}, 
 ControlType -> Checkbox]

which gives

I want to move the control labels, "Sin" and "Cos", to the right side of the respective Checkbox. How do I do this?

using Grid to do the layout is the most flexible way. This way you can arrange labels and content any way you want.

code
Manipulate[
 
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 8},
  PlotStyle -> {
    If[u == True, Automatic, None],
    If[v == True, Automatic, None]}
  ],
 
 Grid[{
   {Checkbox[Dynamic[u, {u = #} &]], "Sin"},
   {Checkbox[Dynamic[v, {v = #} &]], "Cos"}}]
 ,
 {{u, True}, None},
 {{v, True}, None},
 
 TrackedSymbols :> {u, v}
 ]

You can add any Grid options ofcourse. For example, using Spacing and Frame, it now looks like this
Grid[{
  {Checkbox[Dynamic[u, {u = #} &]], "Sin"},
  {Checkbox[Dynamic[v, {v = #} &]], "Cos"}},
 Spacings -> {1, 1},
 Frame -> True
 ],


And now you can add label to the left and to the right if you want. Anything you can do with Grid is allowed.
